# PhoneGap, File copy error: Code = 1,

Tags: file, cordova

file copy error, detail information:

2012-06-12 09:21:38.557 mead_debug[10314:fb03] [INFO] parent_entry := /Users/laiqinyi/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/5EFBD6D1-66EB-4DEC-8AE7-D386729744E9/Documents/dest/
2012-06-12 09:22:34.640 mead_debug[10314:fb03] [INFO] upload error source undefined
2012-06-12 09:22:34.641 mead_debug[10314:fb03] [INFO] upload error target undefined

I follow the API instruction, and do not think there are some thing wrong with this "copyTo" code.
In addition, there are folder "Documents/dest" and file "Documents/readme.txt"
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File

```
**var FileSystem = {
    copy : function(src, dest){
    var parentEntry = new DirectoryEntry({fullPath:("/dest")});
    console.log("parent_entry := " + FileSystem.root_path+"/dest");
    function gotFS(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", null, gotFileEntry, fail);
    }

    function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.copyTo(parentEntry, "file.copy", function(e){console.log("copy okay");}, fail);
    }
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
   }

}**
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
copy : function(fromUrl, toPath, toName){
        console.log("copyFile - From: [" + fromUrl + "] To: " + toPath + " Name: " + toName);
        // Set up some storage
        var destPath = '';
        var destName = '';
        doMoveFile(fromUrl);
        // Called when file needs to be moved / after capture
        function doMoveFile(fileUrl){
            //console.log("doMoveFile - fileUrl: " + JSON.stringify(fileUrl));
            // Remember the source file name just in case it was not passed so reuse it, and for logging
            var destName = fileUrl.name;
            var destPath = fileUrl;
            // Resolve the file system
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(fileUrl,resFSSuccess, resFSError);
            // Called upon successful File System resolution
            function resFSSuccess(entry){
                //console.log("resFSSuccess Success - entry: " + JSON.stringify(entry));
                // Request a file system
                window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
                                         requestFileSystemSuccess, requestFileSystemError);
                // Called upon successful File System request
                function requestFileSystemSuccess(fileSys){
                    // Get the source directory
                    fileSys.root.getDirectory(toPath, {create: true, exclusive:false}, getDestDirSuccess, getDestDirError);
                    // Called upon successful Get Of Destination Directory
                    function getDestDirSuccess(directory){
                        // Get the destination file name, set it if it is blank or not passed by the App
                        toName = (toName) ? toName : destName;
                        // Remember the full path name for the console log
                        fullDestPath = directory.fullPath + '/' + toName;
                        // Make the move
                        entry.copyTo(directory, toName, moveSuccess, moveError);
                        function moveSuccess(){
                            console.log("Successful copy of " + destPath + " to " + fullDestPath);
                        };
                        function moveError(error){
                            console.log("copyError code: " + JSON.stringify(error));
                        };
                    }
                    // Get Destination Dir Failure
                    function getDestDirError(error){
                        console.log("getDestDirError code: " + JSON.stringify(error));
                    };     
                }
                // File System Request Failure
                function requestFileSystemError(error){
                    console.log("requestFileSystemError code: " + JSON.stringify(error));
                };
            }
            // Note File System failure
            function resFSError(error){
                console.log("resFSError code: " + JSON.stringify(error));
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey, I'm getting error `{code: 5}` on `fileSys.root.getDirectory` call. Any ideas?